# how to select the last value in groupby method

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe

```
col1
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
```

I want to select and broadcast the last item every 3 rows, and the wanted result is：

```
col1  col2
 1      3
 2      3
 3      3
 4      6
 5      6
 6      6
 7      7
```

I tried

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].groupby(np.arange(len(df))//3).transform(lambda x: x.loc[-1])
```

But it kept running for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

First idea is use [`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) intead lambda function:

```
df['col21'] = df['col1'].groupby(np.arange(len(df))//3).transform('last')
```

If still is necassary improve performance use `numpy` solution with `np.repeat`:

```
arr = df['col1'].to_numpy()
arr1 = np.repeat(arr[2::3], 3)
lenght = len(arr) % 3
arr2 = np.repeat(arr[-1:], lenght)
df['col22'] = np.concatenate([arr1, arr2]).astype(int)
print (df)
   col1  col21  col22
0     1      3      3
1     2      3      3
2     3      3      3
3     4      6      6
4     5      6      6
5     6      6      6
6     7      7      7
```

**Performance**:

```
#[70000 rows x 1 columns]
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [122]: %%timeit
     ...: df['col20'] = df['col1'].groupby(np.arange(len(df))//3).transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1])
     ...: 
7.61 s ± 356 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [123]: %%timeit
     ...: df['col21'] = df['col1'].groupby(np.arange(len(df))//3).transform('last')
     ...: 
     ...: 
7.28 ms ± 103 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [124]: %%timeit
     ...: arr = df['col1'].to_numpy()
     ...: arr1 = np.repeat(arr[2::3], 3)
     ...: lenght = len(arr) % 3
     ...: arr2 = np.repeat(arr[-1:], lenght)
     ...: df['col22'] = np.concatenate([arr1, arr2]).astype(int)
     ...: 
850 µs ± 18.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to put the changed solution first or drop the first one :)